# Webpack Configuration Properties Overridden by webpack-dev-server

Tags: webpack, webpack-5

I'm facing an issue where properties set in my webpack.config file and sent to webpack.base file are being unexpectedly overridden by configurations from webpack-dev-server. In using webpack-merge, and explicitly set devServer options. Any insights or suggestions on how to troubleshoot and resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated.
This issue is happening while im upgrading webpack from 4 to 5 along with many other dependencies and plugins.